# Tracking Error on a number of benchmarks

Tags: python, function, pandas, numpy, apply

I'm trying to calculate tracking error for a number of different benchmarks versus a fund that I'm looking at (tracking error is defined as the standard deviation of the percent difference between the fund and benchmark).  The time series for the fund and all the benchmarks are all in a data frame that I'm reading from an excel on file and what I have so far is this (with the idea that arg1 represents all the benchmarks and is then applied using applymap), but it's returning a KeyError, any suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_excel('File_Path.xlsx')

def index_analytics(arg1):
    tracking_err = np.std((data['Fund'] - data[arg1]) / data[arg1])
    return tracking_err

data.applymap(index_analytics)
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things that need fixed. First,`applymap` passes each individual value for all the columns to your calling function (`index_analytics`). So `arg1` is the individual scalar value for all the values in your dataframe. `data[arg1]` is always going to return a key error unless all your values are also column names.

You also shouldn't need to use apply to do this. Assuming your benchmarks are in the same dataframe then you should be able to do something like this for each benchmark. Next time include a sample of your dataframe.

```
df['Benchmark1_result'] = (df['Fund'] - data['Benchmark1']) / data['Benchmark1']
```

And if you want to calculate all the standard deviations for all the benchmarks you can do this

```
# assume you have a dataframe with a list of all the benchmark columns
benchmark_columns = [list, of, benchmark, columns]

np.std((df['Fund'].values - df[benchmark_columns].values) / df['Fund'].values, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I see your point about creating a list.  So now, I've created benchmark_columns = data.columns.tolist(), but when I use, the structure, ((data['Fund']) - data[benchmark_columns]) / data[benchmark_columns]).std(), i get an error:

Comment: RuntimeWarning: unorderable types: str() < int(), sort order is undefined for incomparable objects

Comment: `benchmark_columns` should be a subset of your columns. From your above code, you are grabbing all the columns which would be pointless. Choose only the benchmark columns. Also use `.values` when doing the subtraction.

Comment: Any ideas how to calculate rolling Tracking Error? Unfortunately `df.rolling(window).apply(fn)` does not work with functions as tracking difference...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're following the definition of Tracking Error below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Portfolio_Returns': [5.00, 1.67], 'Bench_Returns': [2.89, .759]})
df['Active_Return'] = df['Portfolio_Returns'] - df['Bench_Returns']
print(df.head())

list_ = df['Active_Return']
temp_ = []
for val in list_:
    x = val**2
    temp_.append(x)
tracking_error = np.sqrt(sum(temp_))

print(f"Tracking Error is: {tracking_error}")
```

Or if you want it more compact (because apparently the cool kids do it):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Portfolio_Returns': [5.00, 1.67], 'Bench_Returns': [2.89, .759]})
tracking_error = np.sqrt(sum([val**2 for val in df['Portfolio_Returns'] - df['Bench_Returns']]))
print(f"Tracking Error is: {tracking_error}")
```

[image]

[image]